# Locking terminal size in python?

Tags: python, terminal, locking, size, cmd

I'm wondering if there is any python code I can use to lock the size of my CMD window? I'm making a small text adventure game and  want t at a specific size.

If it helps, I'm using windows 7, but wouldn't mind mac and linux compatible instructions. Thanks.

Comment: Does pygame run on WIndows? I'm not sure, but you might look into that.

Comment: The [conque](https://code.google.com/p/conque) module [conque_sole_subprocess](https://code.google.com/p/conque/source/browse/trunk/autoload/conque_term/conque_sole_subprocess.py) is an example of using `ctypes` to launch and control a win32 console process, including resizing the buffer/window. It would be a bit simpler in your case since you're not creating a hidden console and mirroring its content through shared memory, but still not trivial at all. It would be simpler to just use `pygame`, as Keith suggests.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this is possible. If you want to control a gui directly, you should use a gui package like tkinter
for example

```
from Tkinter import *
window = Tk()
window.minsize(minw, minh)
window.maxsize(maxw, maxh)
```

add a text block to this and treat it just like a cmd window. You can read more about it on the Tkinter [docs](http://www.tkdocs.com/)

Answer (score 1):

you can use [pyWinGUI](http://pywingui.googlecode.com) for emulate text terminal with comctl.Edit control